# CakePHP: getting image from mysql BLOB To iOS

Tags: php, ios, image, cakephp

i'm trying to get an image from database using the following code

```
$this->autoRender=false;
$blob = $this->GeneralNews->findById($id,array("image_data"));
 $image = imagecreatefromstring($blob["GeneralNews"]["image_data"]); 

 ob_start(); //You could also just output the $image via header() and bypass this buffer capture.
 imagejpeg($image, null, 80);
 $data = ob_get_contents();
 ob_end_clean();

echo '<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,' .   base64_encode($blob["GeneralNews"]["image_data"])  . '" />';
```

the result can be seen in the next url 
http://www.thedarkdimension.com/generalNews/displayImage/1678

but when i try to get this via iOS in

```
 NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];        
 UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

the image that i get is empty although there is a data  in (imageData)

i can't figure out the problem but it's most probably came from the PHP side .. cause i tried this URL 
http://www.johnquarto.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/08/gag.jpg
and it's ok with it.

Answer (score 0):

Having had a very quick look it appears that what is returned from the URL http://www.thedarkdimension.com/generalNews/displayImage/1678 is not an image but a document claiming to be of type "text/html". That document isn't actually valid HTML but just contains a single img tag with the source attribute being the image base64 encoded. That makes sense given your PHP code.

I suspect what imageWithData is looking for however is just the jpeg in all its binary goodness.

Therefore you need to change your PHP to set the MIME type to image/jpeg and to just echo the jpeg data as it is - not base64 encoding required. I haven't looked at PHP in so long I don't dare give you example code but hopefully thats enough to get you going.

Comment: This seems to be part of the answer. To assist the OP in achieving this, have a look at the CakePHP `Response` object on how to serve raw image data with CakePHP; http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#sending-files feel free to include this in your answer